# UNION table in second query based on the result of first query in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I am struggling with following problem (in further I provide pseudocode in order to make my example more understandable)

Assume I have 2 queries which result I want to union with each other

What query1 output looks like:

```
ID   OFFER
1    prod_1
2    prod_2
3    prod_2
4    prod_1
```

What query2 output looks like:

```
ID   SEGMENT
1    LOW
2    HIGH
3    MED
999  MED
```

What I need to do is to union results of this 2 queries, but avoid taking row with ID = 999

If there any way to do it using UNION by extracting from query2 rows bases on values of column ID which are present in column ID of query2?

I know that following code is incorrect but it conveys the idea of ​​the question greatly:

```
--query1
(
 SELECT ID, OFFER
 FROM TAB1
 WHERE ID <= 4
) RES1
UNION
--query2
SELECT ID, SEGMENT
FROM TAB1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM RES2)
```

Result should be as following

```
ID   OFFER
1    prod_1
2    prod_2
3    prod_2
4    prod_1
1    LOW
2    HIGH
3    MED
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Just remove the ( ) RES1 from query1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pseudo code comes very close. You can use `WITH` for convenience:

```
WITH q1 AS (SELECT id, offer FROM tab1 WHERE id <= 4)
   , q2 AS (SELECT id, segment FROM tab1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM q1))
SELECT * FROM q1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM q2;
```

(Be aware though that you can get the rows in any order, if you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause.)